# Ember 1.0.pre and 1.0.RC differences

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to familiarize myself with Emberjs, and I am going through [this excellent tutorial](http://trek.github.com/). There is a [link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ZKXyg/) on the page that contains a working example of the tutorial, which is great.

The problem I'm having is when I change the managed resources to the newest versions of Emberjs and Handlebarsjs, [the fiddle no longer works](http://jsfiddle.net/mysticgohan53/E9tt2/).

When I put the code into a local version on my machine, the browser gives me the following warning: Uncaught Error:  - Unable to find template "application".

I would assume that the problem lies in how the template is being called:

```
//In app.js
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});

//In index.html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <h1>Ember Committers</h1>
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

I understand that the Emberjs code is in flux, but when I went trying to find an answer as to why this code did work with a previous version and what to change to make it work, I came up empty.

Help!

Comment: The fiddle link "the fiddle no longer works" doesn't give any error on my browser though, by the way on the local make sure you load libraries in order jQuery then Handlebars then Ember...

Comment: It doesn't give an error in the fiddle, but it also doesn't load like the previous fiddle example. When I check I get [this](http://screencast.com/t/Dg7YnR0NR) in my console. This is pretty bizarre.

Comment: I think the handlebars are not being compiled somehow or you may have forgot to require the template in your module, check once